# How to fix 'sourceMap.map.originalPositionFor is not a function'

Tags: typescript, jhipster, yarnpkg, source-maps

I have a JHipster app, when i try generate a war file by executing:

`mvnw -Pprod package`

it produces a error in command `yarn run webpack:test`:

```
D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:199
    var originalPosition = sourceMap.map.originalPositionFor(position);
                                         ^

TypeError: sourceMap.map.originalPositionFor is not a function
    at mapSourcePosition (D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:199:42)
    at wrapCallSite (D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:343:20)
    at D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:378:26
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.prepareStackTrace (D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:377:24)
    at process.emit (D:\application\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:431:52)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:375:26)
error Command failed with exit code 7.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I think it may be a dependency problem, but I've tried a lot of changes and they did not work